# Cannot convert value of type 'XCUIElement' to expected argument type 'SignUpSetUp'

Tags: swift, xcode-ui-testing

I have created a helper class `SignUpSetUp` in order to sign in to my app instead of reusing code. In this class I have a private function `waitForElementToAppear` to wait for elements in the testing suite to appear. However when using this function it is generating the error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'XCUIElement' to expected argument type 'SignUpSetUp'

Why is this and how do I resolve this?

My code is:

```
import XCTest

class SignUpSetUp: XCTestCase {

    var systemAlertMonitorToken: NSObjectProtocol? = nil

    static let signUpApp = XCUIApplication()
    static let app = XCUIApplication()

    class func signUpApp() {
        // XCUIApplication().launch()
        //signUpSetUp.launch()

        sleep(2)
        let element = app.buttons["Enable notifications"]
        if element.exists {
            element.tap()
        }
        sleep(3)

        let notifcationsAlert = self.app.alerts.buttons["OK"]
        if notifcationsAlert.exists{
            notifcationsAlert.tap()
            notifcationsAlert.tap()
        }
        sleep(2)
        waitForElementToAppear(self.app.tabBars.buttons["Nearby"])
        let nearbyTab = self.app.tabBars.buttons["Nearby"]
        if nearbyTab.exists {
            nearbyTab.tap()
        }
        sleep(2)
        let enableLocation = self.app.buttons["Enable location"]
        if enableLocation.exists {
            enableLocation.tap()
        }
        let allowLocation = self.app.alerts.buttons["Allow"]
        if allowLocation.exists {
            allowLocation.tap()
            allowLocation.tap()
        }
        sleep(2)
        //waitForElementToAppear(self.app.tabBars.buttons.elementBoundByIndex(4))
        let settingsButton = self.app.tabBars.buttons.elementBoundByIndex(4)
        XCTAssert(settingsButton.exists)
        settingsButton.tap()

        let signUpButton = self.app.tables.staticTexts["Sign Up"]
        if signUpButton.exists {
            signUpButton.tap()
        }

    }

    private func waitForElementToAppear(element: XCUIElement,
                                        file: String = #file, line: UInt = #line) {
        let existsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
        expectationForPredicate(existsPredicate,
                                evaluatedWithObject: element, handler: nil)

        waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5) { (error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                let message = "Failed to find \(element) after 5 seconds."
                self.recordFailureWithDescription(message,
                                                  inFile: file, atLine: line, expected: true)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to name a variable (`SignUpSetUp`) the same as your class name?

Comment: Sorry this is correct, edit has been made.

Comment: Don't forget my comment in your last question - method and variable names should start with lowercase letters. And update your question now that you have renamed the variable.

Comment: Thanks, been edited.

Comment: Do you still have an issue now?

Comment: Yes the same issue is still apparent

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error?

Comment: waitForElementToAppear(self.app.tabBars.buttons["Nearby"])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are calling an instance method from a class method.

`waitForElementToAppear` is an instance method, but `signUpApp` is a class method. In order for your code to work, you need to align the two. Remove `class` from the signature of `signUpApp`, and also remove `static` from your two properties, and change references to `self.app` to just `app`.

```
let signUpApp = XCUIApplication()
let app = XCUIApplication()

func signUpApp() { ... }
```

Unless you do want the methods to be on a class/static level, in which case you can align in the other direction.

In terms of best practices, there's no need to have two properties holding an instance of `XCUIApplication` - just have one and use that as they will both function in the same way.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, really helped!!